# Recommendations for preparing a configured Eclipse package for distribution to a dev team

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I'm working on setting up a fully configured Eclipse environment that I will distribute to my team. I'd like to distribute the zip package with all of the desired plugins installed and configured so that upon installing (extracting the zip) we are all using the same IDE (i.e. all have the same plugins, esp with regard to versions, and configuration data).

My current question is regarding the Mylyn plugin. I'd like the package I distribute to be pre-configured to point to our issue tracker. This configuration information is contained in `<workspace>/.metadata/.mylyn/repositories.xml.zip`. However, I question whether it is best practice to distribute the `.metadata` directory. For one thing, this will require an extra step in the installation process. After extracting the Eclipse bundle to the installation directory, the user will need to copy the `.metadata` directory to their workspace. Is this recommended, or is there a better way? Is there a way to put a default `repositories.xml` file in the Eclipse installation directory and let Eclipse put that information in `<workspace>/.metadata` on the first startup of Eclipse?

Is there any administrator documentation on recommended practices for configuring a customized Eclipse environment for distribution?

Are users putting `.metadata` in a version control repository and/or distributing it to users with an Eclipse installation package?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how well it covers your particular Mylyn-specific use case, but Google's [Workspace Mechanic for Eclipse](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic) seems worth a look:

> The Workspace Mechanic automates maintenance of your Eclipse environment by tweaking preferences, adding extension locations, and so on. You can use it to:
>   - Create a consistent environment among groups as large as the entire company, your local team, or even among your own many workspaces
>   - Save time setting up new workspaces
>   - Create tasks that ensure your favorite new preferences are applied to all your current and future workspaces. (This is one of our favorite features!)

Even if it's not supported out of the box, looks like it's built to be extended with your own tasks.